# Non-proper intersections and singular points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety in $\mathbb{P^N}$. Consider an intersection $Z=X\cap\mathbb{P}^n\subset\mathbb{P}^N$ with some subspace $\mathbb{P}^n$ and assume that $\dim Z>\dim X+n-N$. Is it true that for some point $z\in Z$ there always exists a hyperplane $\mathbb{P}^n\subset H\subset\mathbb{P}^N$ such that $X\cap H$ is singular at $z$?

I tried to figure it out by myself, but I know nothing about non-proper intersection of varieties.

Comment: If $X$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^N$, clearly you can find such $\mathbb{P}^n$, but all such intersections will be non-singular, being linear spaces. On the other hand, if $X$ is not contained in any hyperplane, you need no assumption as you have, since you can take a $\mathbb{P}^n$ which intersects $T_{x, X}$ improperly and then it will work.